# Apache Camel Redis: AUTH option?

Tags: redis, apache-camel

how can I specify an AUTH credential when configuring the Apache Camel Redis component? All the operations I want to do (such as LPUSH, but be over an established connection that has already done an AUTH)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define bean and pass it into your connection URI.

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" p:host-name="server" p:port="6379" p:password="foobared" /> 

spring-redis://localhost:6379?connectionFactory=#connectionFactory&command=SUBSCRIBE&channels=foo
```